# Создать простой конвертор на андроиде

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Всем примет! Появилась задач реализовать программу на Андроид, что-то вроде конвертера. Пока, что дается не легко, но пробу реализации калькулятора прошли более менее успешно.
Вопрос заключается в следующем, если у кого-то набросок исходного кода приложения, в котором есть список "видов рассчетов" и при нажатии на расчет переходило на новое полотно с определенным количество полей (необходимых для ввода). Максимальное количество полей для ввода: 3.
Я нашел в интернете исходник с названием "AndroidListView". Там список наименований, при переходе на который появляется детальная страничка, однако это одна страничка для каждого пункта списка, меняется название. Пытался подстроится под такую логику, но не тут то было. Создал 3 поля и хотел скрыть 3-ие поле по умолчанию(для некоторых расчетов потребуется только 2) и на этом застрял. Приложение просто вылетает. Есть ли у кого-то наброски или идеи как выйти с этой ситуации. Спасибо всем за внимание. Внизу листинг:

```
   public class AndroidListViewActivity extends ListActivity {


   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // storing string resources into Array
        String[] adobe_products = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.adobe_products);

        // Binding Array to ListAdapter
        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.label, adobe_products));

        ListView lv = getListView();

        // listening to single list item on click
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
              int position, long id) {
              EditText InputС = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.InputC);

                 InputС.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "tabId = " +    , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              // selected item
              String product = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

              // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
              Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListItem.class);
              // sending data to new activity
              i.putExtra("product", product);
              startActivity(i);

          }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Что то не понятна логика , что за EditText при клике на айтем списка ? Как это должно работать ?

Answer (score 1):

Путаюсь в ваших терминах: "страничка", "полотно", "вид расчета". Я так понял у вас есть `ListView`, при нажатии на его пункт нужно перейти на другую `Activity` и там в зависимости от выбранного пункта, скрыть(или не скрывать) один из `EditText`?

---

Это, я полагаю, ваш код? Который и должен делать `EditText` видимым на новом "полотне"?

```
EditText InputС = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.InputC);
InputС.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Тогда не мудрено, что приложение падает. Это нужно делать в `SingleListItem`

```
 Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListItem.class);
 i.putExtra("product", product);
 i.putExtra("isVisible", true); //нужно ли показать
 startActivity(i);
```

В `SingleListItem`, в `Oncreate()` получить данные

```
EditText InputС = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.InputC);

boolean isVisible = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("isVisible", false); 
if(isVisible){
    InputС.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: Да, вы меня правильно поняли. Однако видимо я Вас не правильно понял. У меня не получилось, чтобы поле скрылось. Если у Вас есть парочку минут, не могли Вы дать свои контактные данные ( скайп, аська...?)

Comment: При этом, что-то я не так делаю телефон виснит